# Nexus 7 not detected in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, usb, nexus-7

I have the 2013 nexus 7, and im trying to do some application development through eclipse.

I have installed the google USB drivers from the android SDK manager and it confirms they are installed. However my device isnt detected in eclipse. I can see the device in my computer as a media device but I cant run an application through eclipse onto my nexus 7?

Tired of using emulators, and would like to try debugging on my device. Can anyone help?

Comment: what android-sdk version are you having in eclipse ?

Comment: Is the device in Debug Mode? also what operating system are you using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: In eclipse I have installed all of the 4.0 and above SDKS and im running a windows machine.

Comment: And yes the device is in debug mode, I can see the device on my computer, i can go into the file structure of the device, I just cant seem to see it in eclipse. It also says in device manager, that it needs a driver, however I downloaded the driver from the ASUS website and tried to install it, but it says the driver isnt available :s